# How to handle authentication errors in socket.io with socketio-jwt

Tags: socket.io, auth0

Following the example for https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt , I couldn't get the authentication failure to fire.

How are you supposed to handle and configure authentication errors using this library?  I see in the source code that it is supposed to throw an `UnauthorizedError` but I just can't seem to trigger it.

Server side

```
  io
    .on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
      secret: 'test',
      timeout: 7000
    }))
    .on('authenticated', (socket) => {
      console.log('connected user: ' + socket.decoded_token.name);
    });
```

Client side

```
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('authenticate', {token: 'badtoken'}); //send the jwt
  });

  socket.on("error", function(error) {
    // this never fires
    if (error.type == "UnauthorizedError" || error.code == "invalid_token") {
      alert("User's token has expired");
    }
  });
```

Do I need to add an `.on('error, function(error))` on the server code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for jwt, they are actually emitting "unauthorized", not "error".  Change to

```
 socket.on("unauthorized", function(error) {
    // this should now fire
    if (error.data.type == "UnauthorizedError" || error.data.code == "invalid_token") {
      alert("User's token has expired");
    }
  });
```

This bug in the doc and examples was also reported [here](https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt/issues/53).

Comment: oddly enough, the original syntax works if it's configured for a single roundtrip, e.g. `io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({handshake:true})` .. which is very confusing

Comment: That is because using the single round trip it does not allow Socket.IO to complete the connection, so Socket.IO emits the error.  On the second round-trip example, Socket.IO does connect, however since unauthorized,  socketio.jwt is emits the response, in this case unauthorized.  Give a upvote to this answer please if this helped you.